# How exactly is an AngularJS controller defined?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework, angularjs-controller

I have a question related to the syntax of controllers and the way they are declared in AngularJS. I'm fairly certain I know how they work, but my question is related to the syntax.

So I might have something like this:

```
// MODULE:
var weatherApp = angular.module("weatherApp", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

// Home Page Controller:
weatherApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Controller business operation   
}]);
```

The first line declares the `weatherApp` variable which is my module and that's associated to my page. And `module()` is a method that take as parameter the module name and the list of dependencies used by this module. Is that right?

The main question is related to the controller definition.

```
weatherApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Controller business operation   
}]);
```

On the previous `weatherApp` variable (my module) I call the `controller()` method to set the controller settings. So the first parameter is the controller name (`homeController` in this case), followed by an array that first has to contain the list of dependencies (in this case only the `$scope` service provided by AngularJS) and its last element is a function that takes these dependencies as input parameters which implement the controller behavior.

Why does Angular do it this way? Why are the dependencies and the function that implements the controller passed all together in a single array?

Maybe I have some difficulties in understanding this behavior because I came from a Java background where an array can't contain different kinds of objects and where a function is not an object.

Comment: This is mainly to avoid minification/compilation bugs.

Comment: I can recommand you this style guide: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers. Maybe it's good for a beginner to follow a style guide so you don't learn wrong things

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Bad:**

```
weatherApp.controller('homeController', function($scope){
    // Controller business operation   
});
```

When this is minified, parameters are minified and angular will no longer be able to know which dependencies to inject.

**Good:**

```
weatherApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    // Controller business operation   
}]);
```

The array syntax: the dependencies in a string make minification safe.

**Other correct way:**

You can as well inject separatly the dependencies:

```
function WeatherCtrl($scope, $http) {
    // Controller business operation   
}
WeatherCtrl.$inject = ['$scope'];
weatherApp.controller('WeatherCtrl', WeatherCtrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular defines controllers that way because minifiers rename the arguments (e.g. $scope) in the controller method which breaks Angular's dependency injection mechanism. See: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05#a-note-on-minification

Answer (score 0):

The `$injector` has to know what arguments to inject into a function. There are three different ways to tell the injector what to inject.

**Option 1:** Add an attribute called `$inject` to the function:

```
FN.$inject=['a','b']
```

**Option 2:** Use array like annotation:

```
['a','b', function(x,y) {...}]
```

**Option 3:** If there is no `$inject` attribute and no annotation, AngularJS uses the function arguments:

```
function ('a','b') {...}.
```

You always have to use the names of the dependencies, here `a` and `b`, not the dependencies themselves.

Your example uses the second alternative.

The third alternative can't be used if you minify your code, because this will change the argument names.

Answer (score -1):

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])

//with this app reference you define controller like this

app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

   //your stuff


}])
```

//Here i am attaching running code as much simpler as i can

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp',[])
app.controller('myCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){

   $scope.name = "rahul";
   
}])
```

```html
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 //here inculde the angular library first
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
 /*expression for one way binding*/
 

     {{name}} 
     
     
 //ng-model for two way binding   
 
 
<input ng-model="name"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Remember If you want to inculde the jquery include first then the angularjs file